# Intellij spring boot run not working gradle bootRun

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I run SpringBoot using IntelliJ.
[intellij run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QFfa.png)

```
group 'helloworld'

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

configurations {
    runtimeAgent
}

buildscript {
}

dependencies {
    runtimeAgent "org.springframework:spring-instrument"
    runtimeAgent "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver"
}

/** I want this option to work together. When run with IntelliJ **/
bootRun.doFirst {
    def springInstrument = "-javaagent:" + configurations.runtimeAgent[0].absolutePath
    def aspectJWeaver = "-javaagent:" + configurations.runtimeAgent[1].absolutePath
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = [springInstrument, aspectJWeaver]
}
```

When I run through intelliJ I want to have the "bootRun.doFirst" option run with it.
I can't find a way. Help. Thank you.

Comment: Either run bootRun from IntelliJ or just include the additional agent paths in the Run configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for IDE to pick up all the customizations from `build.gradle` script. You will need to use delegation run to Gradle: set Gradle in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Build and run using**.

Otherwise configure the JVM options in Spring Boot Run/Debug Configuration:
[image]